# Round time to exact hour SQL Server

Tags: sql, select, time, rounding

I have this SQL query:

```
select  
    e.Cedula, 
    concat (e.Nombre, ' ', e.Apellido) nombre, 
    C.Descripcion cargo,
    max(case when mo.Sentido = 'Entrada' then cast(mo.FechaHora as time)
    end) as Entrada,
    max(case when mo.Sentido = 'Salida' then cast(mo.FechaHora as time)
    end) as Salida,
    e.Direccion observaciones 
from 
    mambo.dbo.EMPLEADO e
left join 
    mambo.dbo.CARGO c on e.IdCargo = c.IdCargo
left join 
    mambo.dbo.MARCACIONES_PARA_LIQUIDACION mo on e.IdEmpleado = mo.IdEmpleado 
                                              and CAST(mo.FechaHora AS DATE) = '2018-04-25'
where 
    e.IdCentroCosto = 14 
    and e.estado = '1' 
group by 
    e.IdEmpleado, e.Cedula, e.Nombre, e.Apellido, c.Descripcion, e.Direccion
```

Which returns this result:

[Result of Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAsn6.jpg)

Is there a way I could round the time to the nearest exact hour in a range of 15 minutes?

Example:

- if it is 6:45 I want the result to show 7:00
- if it is 6:58 I want the result to show 7:00
- if it is 17:15 I want the result to show 17:00
- if it is 17:01 I want the result to show 17:00

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: "... to the nearest exact hour in a range of 15 minutes" - I'm struggling to work out what the "15 minutes" part of this is meant to mean.

Comment: what i mean is that it should only adjust the time to the closest exact hour if the minutes are: - under the 15 minutes mark (HH:01 - HH:15)
- over the 45 minutes mark (HH:45 - HH:59)

if time is above that mark it should show the exact minutes

Comment: you may want to include at least one example that *doesn't* get rounded in your example then, because I don't think current answers have picked up on this.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . how about just constructing the value yourself?

```
datename(hour, dateadd(minute, 30, max(case when mo.Sentido = 'Entrada' then mo.FechaHora end))) + ':00' as Entrada,
```

The addition of 30 minutes is to facilitate rounding.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this into a function,  some of it can be simplified/removed it is in there to show steps/clarity.

```
DECLARE @TimeCheck AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @TimeCheck = '17:30'

DECLARE @HourOfTime AS INT
DECLARE @MinuteOfTime AS INT

SET @MinuteOfTime = RIGHT(@TimeCheck, 2)
SET @HourOfTime = LEFT(@TimeCheck, 2)

SELECT @HourOfTime, @MinuteOfTime

-- here if the minutes between 0 and 20 then dont add anything, if it is 30 and 59 add 1 to the hours.
-- if you need more options or need to change the logic you can add more WHEN statements or change the numbers for the between
SET @HourOfTime += CASE 
    WHEN @MinuteOfTime BETWEEN 0 AND 29 THEN 0
    WHEN @MinuteOfTime BETWEEN 30 AND 59 THEN 1
END

SELECT CAST(@HourOfTime AS VARCHAR(30)) + ':00'  -- since rounding this will just be hard coded to 00
```